# Design pattern for nested functions in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, nested

I have two Class A, B.

For A, I have two method `callB()`, and `checksomethinginB()`.

For B, I have one method `execute()`.

I use them like:

```
A _a;
_a.callB(); //inside the function, B object _b will be created

//after _b created, in another place, _b will execute _b.execute().
_b.execute()
{
   // I want to use A method checksomethinginB()
}
```

So I don't know a good way to use A method in B, what I can create is to use static functions, but I think there maybe better way, thanks for your suggestion!!

Comment: do you mean inside b.execute() will call checksomethinginB()?

Comment: If `_b` is created inside `_a.callB()`, it would be destroyed after execution of `callB()` and you cannot call `_b.execute()` on it "in another place".

Comment: That can be archieved by returning a pointer or reference? but not a good design though

Comment: Returning a pointer or a reference to a local variable is a serious mistake.

Comment: @Coding Mash B A::callB(){ return B(); } is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either pass the correct instance of `A` to the constructor of `B`, or pass it along whenever needed.

If `checksomethinginB` doesn't need any state in `A` then it can be static of course.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the class details and without an explanation of what your classes actually do, you could consider these options:

1. If there is commonality between class A and B you could consider deriving one from the other. This should not be used unless there is a good reason and not just to enable you to do what you want
2. Modify the function signature of `B:execute` to take a parameter argument that is an instance of class A (or pointer to or reference to an instance of A) so that you can call the `A::checksomethinginB()`
3. Make the function static as you suggest - bear in mind that this is not possible if `checksomethinginB()` requires access to the non-static member variables of A

There are possibly better alternatives, but without more details about your classes and functionality requirements it is hard to say

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why do you want a function in `class A` that operates on `class B` - I would move `A::checksomethinginB()` to `B::checksomething()`. From here, I see two (+1) possibilities:

1. If `A::checksomethinginB` / `B::checksomething` does not use any state from `A`, then you are done..
2. If it does, then it actually uses `A` in it's code, so you need to give him one: probably pass a reference to it.
3. If it only uses `A`'s static parts, you can just use them with `A::staticSomethingNotMentionedBefore` directly.